# Generate formula for (a+b)^2 in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to write a program in Python that generates formula for `(a+b)^2` (display it).
I mean if I provide input as (a+b)^2 the program should generate the output as `a*a + b*b + 2*a*b` The program itself should generate the formula for `(a+b)^2`.

Comment: what's wrong with `ans = (a + b) ** 2`?

Comment: @MattDMo Its built in... I want the program to generate formula,display it and the result .I'll update the question

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand at all what you're asking. How is the program supposed to "generate" the formula, if you don't tell it what formula you want?

Comment: Hm... you can use `eval` to evaluate some expression, or `exec` to define some function - both of them can take string as argument. **WARNING** avoid passing untrusted arguments to the functions.

Comment: So... you want a program taking `(a+b)^2` and returning `a*a + b*b + 2*a*b`?

Comment: @ MattDMo Updated the question... Let the program just generate the formula

Comment: @ GingerPlusPlus Yes...

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni and... the output should be python code?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Yes.. It should be a python program

Comment: 1. **Yes, it's possible**. 2. Python supports using `()` to change the order of calculations, so if the only requiement is to the output must be Python code, you can simply overwrite `^` using `**`. If not, and you don't want to have `()` in output, I'm affraid you have to manually analyze the input, char after char (or maybe someone already done this).

Comment: Do you mean multiply out the brackets instead of "computing"?

Comment: @gingerPlusPlus ok. So you mean to say It cannot be solved in a mathematical way using loops and other things

Comment: @matjoyce Yes.. Thats more appropriate.. I'll edit the question

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni Nope. You can do this, but `I'm affraid you have to manually analyze the input, char after char`, and IMO it needs quite much work.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus..We'll see. It was a question asked in interview

Comment: If you want to throw away brackets and powers using your own code analyzing the input string, you may be interested in [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and maybe in other `str`'s methods.

Comment: It's like writing a calculator; you can use regex. I'll provide you a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the symbolic computing is what you want, you should have a look at the [SymPy project](http://sympy.org/). See the example at the related wiki page (copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymPy#Expansion):

```
>>> from sympy import init_printing, Symbol, expand
>>> init_printing()
>>>
>>> a = Symbol('a')
>>> b = Symbol('b')
>>> e = (a + b)**5
>>> e
       5
(a + b) 
>>> e.expand()
 5      4         3  2       2  3        4    5
a  + 5⋅a ⋅b +  10⋅a ⋅ b  + 10⋅a ⋅b  + 5⋅a⋅b  + b
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all download sympy package by going to cmd and Type : pip install sympy
Then Open Python 3.7 or version >>3

Now Type the Following Code to the Python idle

```
n = int(input("Enter the Power of (a+b) "))
from sympy import init_printing , Symbol ,expand
init_printing()
 a = Symbol('a')
 b = Symbol('b')
 e = (a+b)**n
print( expand(e) )
```

Save as What you Want and Run !!!!
It will 100000000% work and no errors will be seen to you
it is the code what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("enter a "))
b = int(input ("enter b "))
formula = (a**2 + b**2 + 2*a*b)
print("(" , a ,"+" , b , ")**2 =" , formula)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

Type this code:

```
def formula(a,b):
    print((a+b)*(a+b))
    
formula(5,2)
```

In this, you have to type the a and b in your code yourself like I did ( a and b are 5 and 2 respectively)

The output will be the answer:

```
49
```

this is the output for my code. As you change the values a and b and run the program again, the output will be changed again.